# Translated fields in one form (Globalize + Simple Form)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, globalize

I have simple_form (3.2.0) and in combination with globalize (5.0.0) and Rails4, I want to give an option for users to provide translation for two languages (czech and english) in the same profile form. After spent few hours, I am stuck and not sure how to do it.

```
<%= simple_form_for current_user, :url => user_path, html: { data: {type: 'script'}, id: "nonprofit-profile-form" }, remote: true, authenticity_token: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :non_profit, current_user.rolable do |np| %>

<div id="czech" class="tab-content" style="display: none;">
   <div class="row">
       <%= np.input :description, as: :text, label: false, :required => true, placeholder: t(:profiles_nonprofit_field_description), :input_html => { :rows => 16 } %>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="english" class="tab-content" style="display: none;">
   <div class="row">                         
       <%= np.input :description, as: :text, label: false, :required => true, placeholder: t(:profiles_nonprofit_field_description), :input_html => { :rows => 16 } %>
   </div>
</div>

    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Anyone who was solving the same case with the gems above? Thank you for any advices. Miroslav

## Form:

[image]

## SOLUTION

1. Install the gem Globalize Accessors (https://github.com/globalize/globalize-accessors)
2. Add the following code to model:

   ```
   globalize_accessors :locales => [:en, :cs], :attributes => [:description]
   ```
3. Add the following code to controller:

   ```
   def custom_params
       permitted = NonProfit.globalize_attribute_names + [:name] + [:ico] + [:website] + [:non_profit_category_id]
       params[:user][:non_profit].permit(*permitted)
   end
   ```
4. Add the following code to view:

   ```
   <div id="cestina" class="tab-content" style="display: none;">
       <div class="row">
           <%= np.input :description_cs, as: :text, label: false, :required => true, placeholder: t(:profiles_nonprofit_field_description), :input_html => { :rows => 16 } %>
           <div class="remainChars"><span class="usedChars">0</span>/1000</div>
        </div>
   </div>

   <div id="english" class="tab-content" style="display: none;">
        <div class="row">
            <%= np.input :description_en, as: :text, label: false, :required => true, placeholder: t(:profiles_nonprofit_field_description), :input_html => { :rows => 16 } %>
            <div class="remainChars"><span class="usedChars">0</span>/1000</div>
         </div>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: So many time later and here worked too. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution:

1. Install the gem Globalize Accessors (https://github.com/globalize/globalize-accessors)
2. Add the following code to model:

   ```
   globalize_accessors :locales => [:en, :cs], :attributes => [:description]
   ```
3. Add the following code to controller:

   ```
   def custom_params
       permitted = NonProfit.globalize_attribute_names + [:name] + [:ico] + [:website] + [:non_profit_category_id]
       params[:user][:non_profit].permit(*permitted)
   end
   ```
4. Add the following code to view:

   ```
   <div id="cestina" class="tab-content" style="display: none;">
       <div class="row">
           <%= np.input :description_cs, as: :text, label: false, :required => true, placeholder: t(:profiles_nonprofit_field_description), :input_html => { :rows => 16 } %>
           <div class="remainChars"><span class="usedChars">0</span>/1000</div>
        </div>
   </div>

   <div id="english" class="tab-content" style="display: none;">
        <div class="row">
            <%= np.input :description_en, as: :text, label: false, :required => true, placeholder: t(:profiles_nonprofit_field_description), :input_html => { :rows => 16 } %>
            <div class="remainChars"><span class="usedChars">0</span>/1000</div>
         </div>
   </div>
   ```